# Uncomment extension=php_openssl.so in a free host?

Tags: php, openssl

I have a PHP script that needs OpenSSL, I enabled OpenSSL in localhost and it's perfectly working, I uploaded it to my web host and it's not working because it's not enabled! And I don't have access to php.ini.

I'm using 000webhost, can you please give me another way to enable it? It just needs to get uncommented.

Edit:
Just tried using dl(); and they've blocked it. :/

Comment: I think you mean `php_openssl.so`, since this product is likely to be Linux and not Windows. [Here is the spec](http://www.000webhost.com/free-php-hosting), and the answer is no, you probably can't do this. You could ask support, but they would likely say the same.

Comment: Oh yea, probably .so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't. If you want ssl enabled you should contact 000webhost.

Comment: Ugh, do you know any free web host that allows PHP.ini editing or SSL?

Comment: PHP.ini editing: none of them (free hosters) would allow that because that would be an extreme security risk. SSL-module enabled: no don't know any.

Comment: Oh well, gonna get a paid hosting.

Comment: Unless you pay for a VPS you can't edit the php.ini-file yourself, so you want to compare them based on which modules are enabled.